python tkinter app no hte same after build
this is how running my app.py looks like (photo 1) and how it looks after building:

no errors shown, what may the problem be, i tried changing the color, but it is not working, i think the problem is not in the color
this is how he procedure is to getting the app runned, what may the problem be:

pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller app.py
cd dist/app
./app

